# Как получить информацию из API в этом формате?

Tags: axios

Столкнулся с проблемой, новичок в axios`е, какой код будет получать данные из такого вида API? Ибо я пытался что-то сделать, вот пример (но ничего не получилось, ага):

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function testaxios() {

    let res = await axios.get('https://streamcraft.net/api/forum/populars');

    let test = res.data.login;

    console.log(`test: ${test}`)
}

testaxios();
```

Структура ответа (нужно взять login для теста):

```
{"populars":[{"login":"Notice","uuid":"ed3977c3-1e69-3b9b-19f3-83041c6b71f7","reputation":733},{"login":"Aleksey3275","uuid":"bb06a6e0-43fd-11ea-977d-5557488d6d86","reputation":624},{"login":"Mine03","uuid":"923680ce-cb06-e915-3226-6ab89f650691","reputation":617},{"login":"SmartLight","uuid":"254d94d0-02e2-11e9-a7c0-15ed89e3b000","reputation":602},{"login":"GizzMOO","uuid":"2e2d7650-8eea-11ea-b517-7fbff509f2eb","reputation":533},{"login":"NeoD","uuid":"c8dbe345-f2c2-0781-6f43-4cc3cfe0323f","reputation":321},{"login":"xchatos","uuid":"837805a0-5301-11e9-8aa4-47ea0e328458","reputation":308}]}
```

Ошибка:

```
(node:38220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (D:\User.Data\Desktop\vbtg\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (D:\User.Data\Desktop\vbtg\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\User.Data\Desktop\vbtg\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:38220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To
 terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:38220) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Скорее всего просто параметры неправильные, ибо пока тестил запускал со своей машины, поэтому доступ точно есть. Что нужно изменить, чтобы код заработал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
async function testaxios() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://streamcraft.net/api/forum/populars');

        const populars = response.data.populars;
        
        for (const popular of populars)
            console.log(`Login: ${popular.login}`)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

testaxios();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bZS47S7sPOxkjU/4Bt0zrhEtWx0y0CRkhEp8IckzK+ltifIIE9EMIMTuT/mEzoIMewUINruDBIR/jJnbguonqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Куда необходимо вставить вторую часть кода (с клаудом)? Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, новичок в этих всех штуках

Comment: @sc_zoo это просто подключение `Axios`. В вашем случае `require`

Comment: Просто у меня при исполнении идёт куча всякого мусора от клауда (в итоге, ответа нет, ибо оно не проходит клаудфлейр). Что можно с этим поделать?